# How add current date and text

Tags: magento-1.9, date

Need to add today date and 2020096 in `'number' => $consignmentNo`, so it will be 201803222020096$consignmentNo

```
$tracks = array(
    '1'=>array(
        'carrier_code' => $carrier_code,
        'title' => $trackTitle,
        'number' => $consignmentNo
    )
);
```

Unable to figure out, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something like this before:

```
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Ymd');
$id = '2020096';
$consignmentNo = $date . $id . $consignmentNo;
```